# Chrome Inspector: Live CSS editing - won't save

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In the Chrome Inspector - anybody know why sometimes nothing happens when you right-click on your CSS file in "Sources" and click "Save"? The "*" is still there, and my CSS file isn't being read anywhere else.

If I try "Save as", it writes a new CSS file but does not include my recent changes.

I'm using version 25.0.1364.97.

Answer (score 0):

I am using version **25.0.1364.99** of google chrome on a Mac OSX version **10.8.2**

I opened an app i recently wrote and changed with right-click --> "inspect elements" with the right side interacitve CSS box some h1 and colors. Then I clicked "save as" and opened that new css file. All changes were adopted.

So for me it works fine! Maybe you update your version of google chrome.
- You find that helpful? Nice, give me a thumbs up.

Comment: Most of the time "Save" works. It's just that sometimes it doesn't, and I don't know what's causing it.