# Chrome Inspector: Easier way to edit live CSS?

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In the Chrome Inspector, is there a better way to edit live CSS than:

1. Having to switch back and forth between the "Elements" and "Sources" tab
2. Copy / paste your stuff from the inspector stylesheet into your real stylesheet
3. Locating your real stylesheet in the files and folders window in, right-clicking and then choosing "Save"?

The latter [doesn't always work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15052857/chrome-inspector-live-css-editing-wont-save) either.

If a Chrome developer sees this - maybe we could just have one big "Save" button somewhere convenient instead?

Comment: You mean something [like this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qy5obNItQiQ)? (incl. SASS support)

Comment: Yeah, that's the one I mean.

Comment: give [tincr](http://tin.cr/) a try

Answer (score 1):

You can't edit any files using Chrome Inspector. What you do is edit the temporary files that Chrome has downloaded while accessing the requested page. It would be quite a security risk if anyone could process a server's files just by inspecting the html/css code!
Personally, I use Chrome Inspector because it makes it so easy editing CSS live, before copying it to my real css file and uploading it.

Comment: This isn't quite true - though you can't save to the server, you can save on top of your local files.

Comment: @RichBradshaw really? how?

Comment: Indeed this might be a proper answer to the question. Still, you have to save it locally and then upload it, which is somewhat the process I described above.

Answer (score 1):

New versions of Chrome have a feature called workspaces which addresses this issue. You can define which paths on your webserver correspond to which paths on your system, then edit and save with just ctrl-s.

See: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/revolutions2013/

Comment: Moreover, DevTools can immediately pick up your CSS recompiled by Sass, LESS or some other compiler after you have edited the respective .scss/.less workspace file in your Sources panel (see https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/css-preprocessors)